# Allow user to set hours,minutes and seconds in dateTimePicker object

Tags: c#, winforms, time, datetimepicker

How to allow user to add hours,minutes and seconds in dateTimePicker object?

Currently, the datetimePicker only have day/month/year... want to add hours,minutes and seconds.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090024/how-to-add-seconds-to-the-value-of-datetimepicker?rq=1

Comment: Change the Format property to "Time".  If the want Date *and* Time then use "Custom" and change the CustomFormat property.

Comment: Ah, thanks Hans. To twice, i'm looking to change the input of the dateTimePicker, not the value...

Answer (score 2):

Set the Format Property to "Custom" and the CustomFormat Property to include time

```
  dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss";
```

Comment: dd-mm-yy = day- minute - year

Answer (score 1):

You can format to `Custom` and then change the `CustomFormat` to `dd-MMM-yyyy hh : mm : ss tt`

```
datetimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
datetimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh : mm : ss tt"
```